# Deleting and unregistering DLL files during install using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In my `[Files]` section I have the following:

```
; Database password decryption (for PTS importing)
Source: "..\..\..\PTSTools\PTSTools\bin\x86\Release\PTSTools.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; \
    DestName: "PTSTools_x86.dll"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "..\..\..\PTSTools\PTSTools\bin\x64\Release\PTSTools.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; \
    DestName: "PTSTools_x64.dll"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: IsWin64
```

In the `[Run]` section I have:

```
Filename: "{dotnet40}\regasm.exe"; Parameters: "PTSTools_x86.dll /codebase"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{dotnet4064}\regasm.exe"; Parameters: "PTSTools_x64.dll /codebase"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; Check: IsWin64
```

Finally, in the `[UninstallRun]` section I have:

```
Filename: {dotnet40}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u PTSTools_x86.dll; \
     WorkingDir: {app}; \
    Flags: runhidden
Filename: {dotnet4064}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u PTSTools_x64.dll;  \
    WorkingDir: {app}; \
    Flags: runhidden; Check: IsWin64;
```

Now, in this version of my program I have consolidated the functionality of these two DLL files into another set of DLL files:

```
Source: "..\..\..\MSAToolsLibrary\MSAToolsLibrary\bin\x86\Release\MSAToolsLibrary.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "MSAToolsLibrary_x86.dll"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "..\..\..\MSAToolsLibrary\MSAToolsLibrary\bin\x64\Release\MSAToolsLibrary.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "MSAToolsLibrary_x64.dll"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    Check: IsWin64
```

As a result, the `PTSTool` DLL files are no longer required. Now, I know I can simply delete them if they exist:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\PTSTools_x64.dll"
Type: files; Name: "{app}\PTSTools_x86.dll"
```

But as far as I am aware this will not trigger the unregistering of the DLL files as is done in `[UninstallRun]`.

How can I do this? Delete and unregister the DLL files (if they exist) during the install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can implement this easily using the standard sections.

A `[Run]` entry happens only after `[InstallDelete]`. While you need it the other way around to first unregister, before you delete a DLL.

---

So you need Pascal scripting.

Either add [`BeforeInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall&anchor=BeforeInstall) to `[InstallDelete]` and unregister the DLL programmaticaly.

Or add [`AfterInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall&anchor=AfterInstall) to `[Run]` and delete the DLL programmatically.

The latter is less work for you, as you already know how to use `[Run]` to (un)register.

```
[Run]
Filename: {dotnet40}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u PTSTools_x86.dll; \
    WorkingDir: {app}; \
    Check: FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x86.dll')); \
    AfterInstall: DoDeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x86.dll')); \
    Flags: runhidden
Filename: {dotnet4064}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u PTSTools_x64.dll;  \
    WorkingDir: {app}; \
    Check: IsWin64 and FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x64.dll')); \
    AfterInstall: DoDeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x64.dll')); \
    Flags: runhidden
```

```pascal
[Code]

{ Cannot use built-in DeleteFile directly in AfterInstall as it's a function,
{ not a procedure. And this way we can add some error handling too. }
procedure DoDeleteFile(FileName: string);
begin
  if DeleteFile(FileName) then
  begin
    Log(Format('"%s" deleted', [FileName]));
  end
    else
  begin
    MsgBox(Format('Failed to delete "%s"', [FileName]), mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```